# Spring Integration Flow: filter based on headers without SpEl expression

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have the following Spring integration flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow checkoutEventFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(EventASink.INPUT)
        .filter("headers['type'] == 'TYPE_A'") //1
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson(EventA.class)) //2
        .<EventA, EventB> transform(eventA ->
            new EventB(
                eventA.getSomeField(),
                eventB.getOtherField()))
        .handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST))
        .get();
}
```

1) I would like to filter a message based on its headers without using a SpEl expression (look at //1), is it possible?

2) Is there another mechanism for JSON conversion to POJO without //2? I like the way @StreamListener can be written in terms of POJO and conversion is done behind the scenes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without SpEL in the `filter()` you can do a Java lambda instead:

```
.filter(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get("type") == "TYPE_A")
```

The Spring Cloud Stream is opinionated Framework where a JSON is as a default content type for data traveling through the flow and beyond into/from the target messaging system.

The Spring Integration is a library to let you build integration applications. There we just can't have any opinion in regards to some default content type conversion. There there is no any out-of-the-box guessing that you are going to transform your incoming `byte[]` to some POJO because of JSON. Although to honor a bit some possibilities which are visible the same way Spring Cloud Stream does, we have a hook in the POJO method invoker to transform from JSON into expected POJO. But that is done only against custom POJO methods when they also marked with the `@serviceActivator`. From here we can't assume your expectation in the `.transform()` lambda. You need to have some service with method and use it in the:

```
/**
 * Populate a {@link ServiceActivatingHandler} for the
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor}
 * to invoke the {@code method} for provided {@code bean} at runtime.
 * In addition accept options for the integration endpoint using {@link GenericEndpointSpec}.
 * @param service the service object to use.
 * @param methodName the method to invoke.
 * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 */
public B handle(Object service, String methodName) {
```

This way it is going to work the same way you see in Spring Cloud Stream with `@StreamListener`.